# Error in calculation of number of ways to put $20$ identical balls in $4$ labelled boxes if each box contains at most $18$ balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

The number of ways to put $20$ identical balls in $4$ labelled boxes in such a way that each box contains at most $18$ balls is,

$$(a)~~\binom{24}{4}-16~~(b)~~\binom{24}{4}-10~~(c)~~\binom{23}{3}-16~~(d)~~\binom{23}{3}-12~~(e)~~\binom{24}{4}-12$$

My solution:

Answer - Stars bars All balls can go in each box - $4C1\cdot$ Stars bars with $2$ balls and $3$ boxes (Fill $1$ box with $18$ balls leaves $2$ balls and $3$ boxes. AND $4C1$ ways of selecting full box )

$$\begin{align}
&= (23 C 3) - (4 C 1) \cdot ( 4 C 2)\\
&= (23 C 3) - 4 \cdot 6\\
&= (23 C 3) - 24
\end{align}$$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hello @lynxx, welcome to MSE. To type math formulas in your question, use MathJax. See this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: Why are you subtracting off ways with 18 balls in one box? You're allowed to have 18, you only need to subtract off ways with 19 or 20 in one box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so using we know that the number of ways without restrictions is simply $$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$ And using $n=20,r=4$ we get $$\binom{23}{3}$$Now if we put $19$ balls in any one box then we have $\binom{4}1$ ways of selecting the one box and then we also have to select the next box to hold the last ball which can be done in $3$ ways each time, so we get for the case of $19$ balls in one box, $12$ ways that should not be included.
Also for the case of $20$ balls in one box, we get $4$ ways of doing that, so you get in total $16$ cases to be subtracted from the original answer, which leaves us with option c) $$\binom{23} 3 -16$$

Answer (score 0):

We need the coefficient of $t^{20}$ in the expansion $(1+t+\cdots +t^{18})^4$.
We have
\begin{align*}
(1+t+\cdots +t^{18})^4 &= \left(\dfrac{1-t^{19}}{1-t}\right)^4 \\
&= (1-t^{19})^4(1-t)^{-4} \\
&= (1-4t^{19} + \cdots )\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+3}{n}t^n
\end{align*}
and hence equals $\binom{23}{20} - 4\binom{4}{1} = \binom{23}{3} - 16$.